# how to improve performance of a query with multi join, group by and where in postgresql?

Tags: database, postgresql, performance, database-performance

I have a query like this:

```
select c.title, count(b.role) as directors_num  
        from cast_info a
                inner join role_type b on a.role_id = b.id
                inner join movie     c on a.movie_id = c.id
where 1=1
and b.role like '%director%'
and c.title not like '(%' -- if necessary
group by c.title
order by count(b.role) desc
```

I want to improve performance:
I tried **EXPLAIN ANALYSIS** method to see the performance:
here is the output:
[result 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyjoi.png)
and
[result 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haDlv.png)

I tried using indexing and improving database statistics, however I could not improve execution time, what would you suggest?

Comment: `xxx like '%....'` can not make use of an index. The two join conditions *could* make use of indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You should turn on track_io_timing and show `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`.  Also, show the plans as text, not images.

Your best bet is probably a `VACUUM cast_info` followed by `create index on cast_info (role_id, movie_id)`.  This should allow use of an index-only scan on cast_info and so avoid the sequential scan, which is currently taking over half your time all by itself.

Also, your work_mem seems to be extremely low for someone working with large data sets.